# Killing Google Chrome via Task Manager references a Jim I've never heard of

Tags: google-chrome

When I am forced to terminate the process of Google Chrome in the Task Manager, this error shows:

> He's dead, Jim!
>
> Either Chrome ran out of memory or the process for the webpage was terminated for some other reason. To continue, reload or go to another page.

[image: google chrome crash screen]

Who is this Jim that the error is talking about?

Comment: Only Red Shirts ask that question. All the others know not to wear Red. See end for Red Shirt Tribute, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vPWE2Ebz48 Spoof Comic Star Trekkin...

Comment: [I am constantly amazed at how people are unable to answer questions on their own](https://www.google.com.au/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=he's+dead+jim)

Comment: @ta.speot.is Sorry, I just didn't know that phrase has other meaning. That's why my question refers only to who is Jim, rather than the phrase. And [googling Jim wouldn't give me anything](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=jim&oq=jim&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.10298340.10300386.2.10300484.17.8.0.1.1.3.365.908.2j3j0j1.7.0...0.0.OXxzt3bwtWA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7962be1b76d57514&biw=1280&bih=633).

Comment: Yep, Jim gives about 875 million results. Putting in the phrase "He's dead, Jim" tells you there's a lot of Trekkies out there, and even mentions Chrome on the first page of results. Google's pretty good at nailing catch phrases, popular references and quotations. Sometimes you learn things that make you wish you were limited to Bartleby's though. Dr. McCoy's good for the, "I'm a doctor, not a 'profession of the moment'" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Star Trek reference: Dr McCoy regularly said to James (or Jim) Kirk, the captain, [that exact line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0yXqU-w9U0).

Answer (score 1):

It's a [quote from Star Trek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_McCoy#.22He.27s_dead.2C_Jim..22):

> Twenty times on the original Star Trek McCoy declares someone or something deceased with the line, "He's dead", "He's dead, Jim", or something similar; the phrase is considered a catchphrase of the character